# add and remove class on resize button click

Tags: javascript

I have some collapseable panels and i want to add a resize button. For this i've made this javascript code:

```
function myFunction () {
    $(".elementoGrafico").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-12");
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-6");
    });
};
```

the html code is:

```
<div class="col-md-12 ui-state-default elementoGrafico">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" class="component-button max-min-button more-less glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></a>
                   <a href="#" class="component-button resize-button glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small" onclick="myFunction.call(this)"></a>
                   Gráfico 1
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in elemento"> <canvas class="chart" id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. How can make it work? (i want a code that works for all elements, not just one, so i want to do it using class, not id.)

Thank you.

Comment: You can just do `$(this).toggleClass("col-md-6 col-md-12")`

Comment: didn't work. it's bugged

Comment: i've found the solution:
$(".elementoGrafico").each(function() {
  let panel = this;
  $(this).find(".resize-button").click(function() {
    $(panel).toggleClass("col-md-12");
    $(panel).toggleClass("col-md-6");
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

"elemnto1" is not how you grab each class, you're missing the period

`$(".elemento1").each()`

edit:

```
$(".elemento1").click(function() {
    $(this).toggle("col-md-12");
    $(this).toggle("col-md-6");
});
```

Comment: worked, but i want to resize only the element that i clicked. i think my semantics are wrong

Comment: it resizes to 6 and back to 12 in one click

Comment: looks like it's getting more than on click sometimes. and sometimes the click don't  work

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction () {
    $( "elemento1" ).each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-12");
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-6");
    });
};
```

Comment: This would only work if the element has exactly one of the `col-md-` classes already. If no `col-md-` is specified first, it will add both `col-md-12` and `col-md-6` by toggling them both on at the same time.

Comment: @ReactiveRaven, I think your comment is based on a misunderstanding of the question. If you look at the the question, user removes one of the `col-md-` classes and adds another both in the  `if` and `else` clauses, meaning at least one of those classes already exist in his HTML. I responded based on the question.

Comment: the toggleclass works, but some clicks are being missed. some times i have to click more than one time to make it work. why?

Comment: If you have to click twice, it means the element probably doesn't have one of the `col-md-` classes before you click. Your question makes one think otherwise. If before you click, certain elements don't have either `col-md-` classes, please update your question to reflect that, or let me know so I update my answer.

Comment: i'll update the question and show how my code is right now